# How to change column data type of metadata table . What will be the update statement be like?

Tags: ssms, metadata

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2SHn.jpg)

I need to change data type from int to bigint. This has to be changed in metadata as well after changing the source table . Please someone get back to me fast .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update column data type in metadata table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68882329/update-column-data-type-in-metadata-table)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Alter Command.

```
ALTER TABLE tableNAme ALTER COLUMN columnName bigint;  
GO
```

This will automatically change your metadata table as well. you don't need to change it yourself